# C# passing abstract class instance to method that is overloaded on derived classes

Tags: c#, class, methods, overloading, abstract-class

So how can I make it work that I have an abstract Base class and classes A,B,C that are derived from the Base. I have a doStuff method that has 3 overloads, each for class A,B and C but when I call doStuff from an other method that takes in a Base type parameter it somehow throws an error. So in a nutshell, I want C# to infer which overloded method to call on the passed parameter.

I get error CS1503:

> cannot convert from 'T' to 'A'

```
public abstract class BaseClass{}

public class A : BaseClass{}
public class B : BaseClass{}
public class C : BaseClass{}

public void DoStuff(A a){}
public void DoStuff(B b){}
public void DoStuff(C c){}

public void StartDoStuff(BaseClass baseclass){
    DoStuff(baseclass);
}
```

Comment: It won't work, because think about what should it do when you BaseClass is type `D`. Can you create a more contextual example?

Comment: What method to call is determined at compiletime you want something determined at runtime. So you need to detect the actual type (for example via a pattern matching switch on the type) and call the proper overload from there.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler can't assume that every inheriting class of `BaseClass` has a corresponding `DoStuff` implementation.  *Unless* it's on `BaseClass` itself:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract void DoStuff();
}
```

Then every class which inherits `BaseClass` *must* (as enforced by the compiler) provide an implementation of this method.  And you can invoke it directly on the object:

```
public void StartDoStuff(BaseClass baseclass){
    baseclass.DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: But what if DoStuff is in a different class? (Also I'm thinking of switching Baseclass to an interface)

Comment: @ÁkosDánielBollók: *"But what if DoStuff is in a different class?"* - Then the design is probably wrong.  Given the code shown, why does it need to be in a different class?  If the goal is for every inheriting class to have a corresponding implementation for this method, why isn't this method enforced by the base class?  To put it another way... If the goal is to use inheritance, why not use inheritance to achieve that goal?

Comment: As long as it is derived from `BaseClass`, it is able to call the `DoStuff`

Answer (score 2):

Since overload resolution happens at compile time, but the actual type (the runtime type) of the object passed as method argument is only known at runtime, the C# compiler does not know which overload must be called.

A possible solution is to switch on the actual type of the object:

```cs
public void StartDoStuff(BaseClass baseclass)
{
    switch (baseclass) {
        case A a: DoStuff(a); break;
        case B b: DoStuff(b); break;
        case C c: DoStuff(c); break;
        default: throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

---

But a cleaner, object oriented approach would be to have `BaseClass` declare an abstract `void DoStuff()` method. You can still implement it in another class and inject it as a service into the constructor of the implementing classes.

```cs
public interface IStuffService
{
    void DoStuff();
}

public abstract class BaseClass : IStuffService {
    public abstract void DoStuff();
}

// Only class A as an example
public class A : BaseClass
{
    private readonly IStuffService _service;
    public A(IStuffService service) => _service = service;

    public override void DoStuff() => _service.DoStuff();
}
```

Now you can call it with

```cs
public void StartDoStuff(BaseClass baseclass)
{
    baseclass.DoStuff();
}
```

Of course you can have different, specialized `IStuffService` implementations for specialized classes.